# Como extrair um trecho especifico de uma string

Tags: r, regex

Vamos que eu tenha esta URL extraída

```
/ac/rio-branco/xpto-xyz-1-0-16-5-abcd-a1G57000003DE4QEAW
```

E eu quero somente o trecho que começa com `a1G`, alguém sabe como consigo somente este trecho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer usando o pacote `stringr` e expressões regulares.

No seu caso, eu faria assim:

```
s <- "/ac/rio-branco/xpto-xyz-1-0-16-5-abcd-a1G57000003DE4QEAW"
stringr::str_extract(s, "a1G\\S+\\s*")
[1] "a1G57000003DE4QEAW"
```

Esse código funciona mesmo se `s`for um vetor, então funcionaria em um `data.frame` da seguinte forma:

```
df$extrair <- stringr::str_extract(df$url, "a1G\\S+\\s*")
```

Note que se você não possuir o pacote `stringr` instalado, precisará instalá-lo usando o comando `install.packages("stringr")`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Answer (score 1):

Extrair parte de uma string utilizando só o pacote `base` é bem chato, mas possível. Escolhi uma expressão regular mais simples do que a do Daniel, já que você não foi muito específico. Ficaria assim:

```
> s <- "/ac/rio-branco/xpto-xyz-1-0-16-5-abcd-a1G57000003DE4QEAW"
> regmatches(s, gregexpr("a1G.+", s))
[[1]]
[1] "a1G57000003DE4QEAW"
```

Veja que o resultado é uma lista, que vai conter um elemento para cada string do vetor `s`, com todas as ocorrências da expressão regular. Se você quiser apenas um vetor como output, pode usar unlist:

```
> s <- c("/ac/rio-branco/xpto-xyz-1-0-16-5-abcd-a1G57000003DE4QEAW", "abcsda1G000")
> regmatches(s, gregexpr("a1G.+", s))
[[1]]
[1] "a1G57000003DE4QEAW"

[[2]]
[1] "a1G000"

> unlist(regmatches(s, gregexpr("a1G.+", s)))
[1] "a1G57000003DE4QEAW" "a1G000"
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!